# How can I find and and install drivers for my laptop?

Tags: 16.04, drivers

How can I search and install drivers for my laptop's devices?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My laptop is HP-ProBook-470-G0.

Comment: I would think `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` should help!

Comment: Generally the drivers are in the kernel. First step is to identify your hardware and what is not working.